# Ansible - win_file module - force deletion if file in use

Tags: windows, ansible, delete-file

We are using ansible win_file module to delete a particular folder in a Windows Server machine with the following code:

```
- name: Delete <folderName> directory
  win_file: path=C:\<pathToFolder>\{{target_environment}}\<folderName> state=absent
  tags: <folderName>
```

The problem: When a file from that directory is open in another program at the same time the ansible role runs, it fails saying:

- "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Now, i understand the error, but i am looking for suggestions to force this deletion, even if the file is in use, or if there is other module that i don't know that can't resolve this problem.

(currently using ansible 2.4.6)

Answer (score 2):

So, after some searching and digging, i came out with a solution, i found a similar ansible module that can do the job, **win_shell**.

I resolved the problem with the following code:

```
  name: Delete <folderName> directory
  win_shell: Remove-Item –path <folderName> –recurse -force
  args:
    chdir: C:\<pathToFolder>\{{target_environment}}
    removes: C:\<pathToFolder>\{{target_environment}}\<folderName>
  tags: <folderName>
```

- removes: checks if the folder exists else skips the task
- force: does the trick of what i want, delete the folder and all his files even if some of the files are in use or open in any program.

Comment: Hello Veiga, I am still facing same issue even if I se win_shell module with force option

Comment: Hi @SureshchandraJarugula, first, do you know the reason why you cant delete it? if you try it manually it won't work either? for me the problem was trying to delete a file that was open in another program, but the force worked for me..

Comment: for me file is holding by the file explorer process and that is not getting killed forcefully

Comment: May be its case sensitive per : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html this? `Remove-Item -Path <path> -Force`